# Why is my measured value of magnetic flux in the experiment larger than the theoretical value calculated?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-technique

I recently did an experiment to investigate the emf induced in a coil by letting a magnet fall through a coil. The voltage was measured by a voltage sensor, and then plotted against time on a Capstone program. The area under the curve was calculated by the program to give the magnetic flux.

Experimental Setup:

- a 2500-turn coil was used
- it was clamped 30cm above the table
- a magnet was placed 5 cm above the coil and dropped
- a voltage sensor was connected to the coil and the 550 Universal Interface box.
- Sampling rate is 5000Hz, and data recording starts when voltage >= 0.1V
- Stops recording when t = 0.5s

I calculated the theoretical value by using the formula flux = NBA, and realise the error was about 60%. The measured value is larger than the theoretical value. What are the possible causes? Is it because of the presence of Earth's magnetic field?

Actually, it would be great if anyone could tell me most common sources of errors in electromagnetic induction experiments. Previously, I experimented the force on a wire with current under a magnetic field, and ended up with a force even when there is no current running through (with the electromagnet was turned on). Sometimes I obtain weird results but have no idea where these large errors come from.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. Please provide more details of your set up, consider editing your question to add diagrams and more details that would help to understand what could be wrong.